# League/Ranking link

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, featured-tag

[The league ranking table link](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)  that is available on the SO profile page is missing (from the same location) on at least the following SE sites

- English Language and Usage
- Super User
- The Workplace
- Programmers
- Information Security
- Money
- Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair*

SO/MSO Profile Page:

> [image: SO Rep Panel]

<sup>Clicking on the link sends me [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/1933347#1933347). Your results may vary.</sup>

Non-SO/MSO Profile Page:

> [image: Non-SO Rep Panel]

Any reason why?

<sup>I'd previously [asked this question on The Workplace meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2518/2536) and I was referred here.</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug; the setting got accidentally turned off somehow. Should be working again now.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, but I still can't see the link on my page I'm afraid

Comment: @kolossus I swear it was working when I posted this. :) Clearly something wonky is happening (I just checked a bunch of sites and it's disappeared again.) I'll get someone to look into it next week.

Comment: Calculating this value for everyone on every site everywhere turned out to be a *little bit* expensive - it'll get done eventually, but not until someone has time to keep it from devouring us all.

Comment: @Shog9 - so "status-by-design" then?

Comment: "status-waiting-on-nick-to-have-time-to-fix", @kolossus

Comment: @Shog9 - understood.